# python site-packages has multiple paths on Mac

Tags: python, path, package

why i got two different paths of site-packages of Python:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

latest day, i installed sphinx-doc in my Mac by:

```
<i>pip install -U Sphinx</i>
```

this action installed a new python version (2.7.13), after that `"ImportError"` appeared when `import third package (numpy, pymong etc.)`

I tried to solve this problem, i found i got two versions `Python 2.7.10 (old)` and `2.7.13 (new)`

So, site-packages path has two paths:

```
(Old) /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

(New) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Finally, the problem was fixed by add "Old Path" into PYTHONPATH. But i don't know why this two paths used by python?

Thank you